# MySQL query to append most recent result

Tags: mysql, max

I have two MySQL tables and would like to select the highest value results from table2 and append these to table 1.

Table 1 contains ID, MSISDN (14 digit number)

Table 2 contains ID, MSISDN, field2, date

I want to return a list of all MSISDNs in table 1 and also the result for table2.field2 and table2.date where table2.date is the maximum value for the matching MSISDN.

How would I do this? I know I need to use MAX but I'm not sure how to construct the subquery to add the correct result for table2.field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typically, you would do this by

- Creating a subselect containing the maximum date for each id
- Joining this subselect with your original table to return the additional columns

*Note that **if** there are two identical (MSISDN, date) records, they will both be returned.*

**SQL Server**

```
SELECT  t1.MSISDN
        , t2.field2
        , t2.date
FROM    Table1 AS t1
        INNER JOIN Table2 AS t2 ON t2.MSISDN = t1.MSISDN
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  MAX(date) AS date, MSISDN
          FROM    Table2
          GROUP BY
                  MSISDN
        ) t2max ON t2max.MSISDN = t2.MSISDN
                   AND t2max.date = t2.date
```

Comment: Thanks for this. Do you mean `MAX(date) as DATE` or `MAX(MSISDN) as MSISDN`? I need the most recent date for each MSISDN but the matching field2 for that date and MSISDN.

Comment: @MatthewPort - It should have been `MAX(date)`. I have fixed my error.

Comment: great, thanks. My queries are taking hours to run (table2 is 97m rows) so it takes a long time to wait to see if the result is as expected.

Comment: Even with 97m rows, with proper indexing it should not take *hours*.